# Trying to Parse XML with JS...not working

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having issues parsing XML with jS. Basically, I want to take content from an RSS feed and automatically post it on my website.  I'm not showing any errors, but I could be wrong on that. Well, I guess I am wrong seeing how it would work if there weren't any errors. Any ideas?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var xmlDoc;
 function loadxml() {
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = readXML;
  xmlDoc.load("test.xml");
}

function readXML()
{
   if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4)
   {
    //Using documentElement Properties
    //Output company
    alert("XML Root Tag Name: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);

    //Using firstChild Properties
    //Output year
    alert("First Child: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[1].firstChild.tagName);

 //Using lastChild Properties
 //Output average
 alert("Last Child: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[1].lastChild.tagName);

 //Using nodeValue and Attributes Properties
 //Here both the statement will return you the same result
 //Output 001
 alert("Node Value: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].attributes[0].nodeValue);
 alert("Node Value: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue);

 //Using getElementByTagName Properties
 //Here both the statement will return you the same result
 //Output 2000
 alert("getElementsByTagName: " + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue);

 //Using text Properties
 //Output John
 alert("Text Content for Employee Tag: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].text);

 //Using hasChildNodes Properties
 //Output True
 alert("Checking Child Nodes: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].hasChildNodes);
 }
 }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body onload="loadxml();">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ActiveXObject works only with IE

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use ActiveX rather than a javascript library like jQuery? - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML

Comment: No reason at all....I just did a google search and found a tutorial and went with that. Thanks, I'll check out the JQuery tutorial.

Comment: Although very convenient, using jQuery is not mandatory. You won't burn in hell for not using it. Moreover, I really recommend to learn JS without it to fully understand what jQuery does and how. It'll definitely make you a better programmer.

Comment: Thanks. I know javascript OK, the biggest issue is I don't have to use it very much, so I'm always having to relearn a few things. I'm completely new to JQuery. So my question is how do I get a file off the internet (RSS Feed) so JQuery can parse it? I'm wanting to post content from a blog onto a website automatically. I used the example in the link above as well as some other online tutorials. I think I need to use the jQuery function "get", but I'm not 100% sure. Here's a JSFiddle that I played with. IT didn't work, but I think it's close. http://jsfiddle.net/deadendstreet/DytGM/1/

Comment: Try [Fast XML Parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser)